# How to filter manytomany field values in django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to query values from model, I want to include manytomanyfield values in query but now I am getting some numbers instead of values, I am using modelviewset in views.py file.

I know what have done is wrong, How to do this in right way

models.py

```
class TrainingDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TrainingDetails.objects.all().order_by('Name')
    serializer_class = TrainingDetailsSerializer
```

views.py

```
class TrainingDetails(models.Model):
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    TrainerName = models.ManyToManyField(TrainerDetails, blank=True, related_name='trainer')
    Agenda = models.FileField()
    Date = models.ManyToManyField(Date,blank=True, editable= True, related_name='date')
    Data = models.ManyToManyField(TrainingData, blank=True, related_name='data')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

serializers.py

```
class TrainingDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TrainingDetails
        fields = ('Code', 'Name', 'TrainerName', 'Agenda' , 'Date' , 'Data' )
```

I'm getting in response,

```
[
    {
        "Code": "TRA123",
        "Name": "something",
        "TrainerName": [
            5,
            6
        ],
        "Agenda": "something",
        "Date": [
            2
        ],
        "Data": [
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

I want,

```
[
    {
        "Code": "TRA123",
        "Name": "something",
        "TrainerName": [
            'john' , 'james'
        ],
        "Agenda": "something",
        "Date": [
            '19/10/2020'
        ],
        "Data": [
            'something'
        ]
    }
]
``
```

Comment: What is `'19/101/2020'` ? How did you store that value in your database?

Comment: sorry edited in to correct date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [StringRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield), for example:

```
class TrainingDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    TrainerName = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TrainingDetails
        fields = ('Code', 'Name', 'TrainerName', 'Agenda' , 'Date' , 'Data' )
```

It should be noted that `StringRelatedField` looks for the `__str__` of the related model, in your case the `TrainerDetails`.